# Manipulate SearchCenter how showing the results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, search-results

is it posible to manipulate the searchcenter result list? 
I need for results from a special library an other Link or another name field.

[image]

For Test i need an other Field e.g. a Userdefiend Title
and i must manupulate the URL from the HyperLink.

Thanks

Mario

Answer (score 1):

The display of the results on controlled by XSLT in the Core Results web part.

For a start on how to change it follow [Walkthrough: Add a Tab and Custom Search Page with Enterprise Search Web Parts to the Search Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms584031%28v=office.12%29.aspx) you can skip the add tab and create pages part (and yes it also applies to SharePoint 2010)